# Data Structure for Storing the Excel Data in C#

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary, linked-list, structure

I am searching for an optimal way for storing the Data that I am reading from an Excel Sheet :

[image]

The Sheet Name as well as the Properties per sheet are dynamic as per the data in the Data Base.

For now I have the below structure in Place

```
Class ItemType
{
            name;
             action
}

Class Property
{
            name;
             List<string> values;
}
Dictionary <ItemType, List<Property>>  data;
```

But I am pretty new to C# , is there a better way of achieving the above requirement.

Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the data? Most libraries already have classes for represent the file, why not stick to them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better way to implement the CRUD operation using C#.

First you have to create the Excel file, then you have to perform the CRUD operation here with created Excel file.

Then Create a Read method to read the contents and Update method to update the records.

I am providing the link here to better understanding of the implementation.

[Link for Implementation sample.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-update-delete-and-reading-the-excel-file-in-c-sharp/)